# Automating the process of determining which boxes to load on each flight for freight company

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interview-questions, dependency-injection, .net-core

I was given a test assignment for the interview of the company and below is the code that I shared with them. I developed it using .NET 6 (Core) Console application.

Actual problem statement:

**Coding Exercise**

*Description*

- For the purposes of this exercise, it’s expected to implement a console application driven from a main method,the application does not need to be interactive
- It’s expected that you use C# or Java for this exercise
- This exercise is meant to allow you to display your skills and experience, the use of best practices and objectoriented design principles such as SOLID is expected
- The use of a database is not required
- It is expected that the take-home part of this should not take more than 1.5 hours to complete
- Use the included orders file for the list of orders
- If you move on to the next phase of the interview, it will be expected that you bring this code in for a peer exercise where you’ll be expected to work on new User Stories iterating on this code.

*Scenario*

Transport.ly is a brand-new company that aims to provide efficient and fast air freight services; they currently have 3 planes the planes are scheduled to fly daily at noon. For this exercise, there are only 2 days of flights scheduled.

*Day 1:*

Flight 1: Montreal airport (YUL) to Toronto (YYZ)
Flight 2: Montreal (YUL) to Calgary (YYC)
Flight 3: Montreal (YUL) to Vancouver (YVR)

*Day 2:*

Flight 4: Montreal airport (YUL) to Toronto (YYZ)
Flight 5: Montreal (YUL) to Calgary (YYC)
Flight 6: Montreal (YUL) to Vancouver (YVR)

With each flight returning to the YUL at midnight.

Each plane has a capacity of 20 boxes each.

The company’s sales department has been able to sell 99 orders that are sending boxes to Toronto, Calgary, and Vancouver, these orders are found in the attached json file. Each box represents 1 order.

As a member of the software engineering department you are asked to develop an application that can automate the process of determining which boxes to load on each flight.

User Stories - Take-Home

USER STORY #1

As an inventory management user, I can load a flight schedule similar to the one listed in the Scenario above. For this story you do not yet need to load the orders. I can also list out the loaded flight schedule on the console.

Expected output:

Flight: 1, departure: YUL, arrival: YYZ, day: 1
...
Flight: 6, departure: <departure_city>, arrival: <arrival_city>, day: x

USER STORY #2

As an inventory management user, I can generate flight itineraries by scheduling a batch of orders. These flights can be used to determine shipping capacity.Use the json file attached to load the given orders.

The orders listed in the json file are listed in priority order ie. 1..N

Expected output:

order: order-001, flightNumber: 1, departure: <departure_city>, arrival: <arrival_city>, day: x
...
order: order-099, flightNumber: 1, departure: <departure_city>, arrival: <arrival_city>, day: x

if an order has not yet been scheduled, output:

order: order-X, flightNumber: not scheduled

**Any suggestions/comments are greatly appreciated to improve the code further.
Thanks.**

**Program.cs**

```
using FrieghtManagment;
using FrieghtManagment.Abstraction;
using FrieghtManagment.Models;
using FrieghtManagment.Repositories;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IScheduleRepository, ScheduleRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IFileReader, JsonFileReader>();
            services.AddScoped<FlightScheduleFactory>();
        })
        .Build();

        DisplayAndRead((FlightScheduleFactory)host.Services.GetRequiredService(typeof(FlightScheduleFactory)));

        host.Run();


    }
    static void DisplayAndRead(FlightScheduleFactory flightScheduleFactory)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        
        Console.WriteLine("=======Transport.ly Freight Management=======");
        Console.WriteLine("\nDefault flight schedule \n");
        var defaultFlightScheduleInstance = flightScheduleFactory.GetFlightTypeScheduelInstance(FlightTypeSchedule.DefaultFlight);
        defaultFlightScheduleInstance.DisplayFlightSchedule();
        Console.WriteLine("\nLoaded orders flight schedule \n");
        var loadedOrderFlightScheduleInstance = flightScheduleFactory.GetFlightTypeScheduelInstance(FlightTypeSchedule.LoadedFlight);
        loadedOrderFlightScheduleInstance.DisplayFlightSchedule();
    } 

}
```

**Abstraction**

**Repositories**

```
internal interface IOrderRepository
{
    IList<Order> GetOrders();
}
internal interface IScheduleRepository
{
    IList<Schedule> GetSchedules();
}
```

**Generice Interfaces**

```
internal interface IFileReader
{
    Dictionary<string, Order> ReadAll();
}
internal interface IFlightSchedule
{
    void DisplayFlightSchedule();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
   internal class JsonFileReader : IFileReader
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Order> ReadAll()
        {
            var jsonFile = File.ReadAllText("coding-assigment-orders.json");
            var serializationOptions = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase };
            var ordersDictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Order>>(jsonFile,serializationOptions);

            return ordersDictionary;
        }
    }

internal class DefaultFlightSchedule : IFlightSchedule
    {
        private readonly IScheduleRepository _scheduleRepository;
        public DefaultFlightSchedule(IScheduleRepository scheduleRepository)
        {
            _scheduleRepository = scheduleRepository;
        }
        public void DisplayFlightSchedule()
        {
            var scheduledFlights = _scheduleRepository.GetSchedules();

            foreach (var scheduledFlight in scheduledFlights)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Flight:{scheduledFlight.FlightNumber}, Departure:{scheduledFlight.Source}, Arrival:{scheduledFlight.Destination}, Day:{scheduledFlight.Day}");
            }
        }
    }

 internal class LoadedFlightSchedule : IFlightSchedule
    {
        private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
        private readonly IScheduleRepository _scheduleRepository;
        public LoadedFlightSchedule(IOrderRepository orderRepository, IScheduleRepository scheduleRepository)
        {
            _orderRepository = orderRepository;
            _scheduleRepository = scheduleRepository;
        }
        public void DisplayFlightSchedule()
        {
            var scheduledFlights = _scheduleRepository.GetSchedules();
            var orders = _orderRepository.GetOrders();
            List<Order> loadedOrders = new List<Order>();

            foreach (var flight in scheduledFlights)
            {
                var ordersToBeLoaded = orders.Where(x => x.IsNotLoaded() && x.Destination == flight.Destination).OrderBy(x => x.Priority).Take(20).ToList();

                if(ordersToBeLoaded.Any())
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nLoaded Orders for destination {flight.Destination} for flightnumber {flight.FlightNumber} is {ordersToBeLoaded.Count}\n");

                foreach (var order in ordersToBeLoaded)
                {
                    order.Schedule = flight;

                    Console.WriteLine($"order:{order.Ordernumber},flightnumber:{order.Schedule.FlightNumber}, departure:{order.Schedule.Source}, arrival:{order.Schedule.Destination}, day:{order.Schedule.Day}");

                    loadedOrders.Add(order);
                }
            }          

            Console.WriteLine("\nUnloaded Orders:\n");

            var unloadedOrders = orders.Except(loadedOrders);

            foreach (var item in unloadedOrders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"order:{item.Ordernumber}, destination:{item.Destination}, flightnumber:not scheduled");
            }

        }
    }
```

Factory Class

```
 internal class FlightScheduleFactory
    {

        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
        private readonly IScheduleRepository _scheduledRepository;
        public FlightScheduleFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOrderRepository orderRepository, IScheduleRepository scheduleRepository)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _orderRepository = orderRepository;
            _scheduledRepository = scheduleRepository;
        }

        public IFlightSchedule GetFlightTypeScheduelInstance(FlightTypeSchedule flightTypeSchedule)
        {
            if (flightTypeSchedule == FlightTypeSchedule.DefaultFlight)
                return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DefaultFlightSchedule>(_serviceProvider, _scheduledRepository);

            return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<LoadedFlightSchedule>(_serviceProvider, _orderRepository, _scheduledRepository); ;


        }


    }
```

**Models**

```
public enum FlightTypeSchedule
    {
        DefaultFlight,
        LoadedFlight
    }

 internal class Order
    {
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public string Ordernumber { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }

        public bool IsNotLoaded()
        {
            return Schedule == null;
        }
    }

internal class Schedule
    {

        //use auto properties
        public int FlightNumber { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            //use string interpolation
            return $"{FlightNumber}. Source: {Source},  Destination: {Destination}, Day: {Day}";
        }

    }
```

**coding-assignment-orders.json**

```
{
    "order-001": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },
    "order-002": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },
    "order-003": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },
    "order-004": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },
    "order-005": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-006": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-007": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-008": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-009": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-010": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-011": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-012": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-013": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-014": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-015": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-016": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-017": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-018": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-019": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-020": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-021": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-022": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-023": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-024": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-025": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-026": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-027": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-028": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-029": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-030": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-031": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-032": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-033": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-034": {
        "destination" : "YYZ"
    },"order-035": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-036": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-037": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-038": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-039": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-040": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-041": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-042": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-043": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-044": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-045": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-046": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-047": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-048": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-049": {
        "destination" : "YYE"
    },"order-050": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-051": {
        "destination" : "YYE"
    },"order-052": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-053": {
        "destination" : "YYE"
    },"order-054": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-055": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-056": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-057": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-060": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-061": {
        "destination" : "YYC"
    },"order-062": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-063": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-064": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-065": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-066": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-067": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-068": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-069": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-070": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-071": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-072": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-073": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-074": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-075": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-076": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-077": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-078": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-080": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-081": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-082": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-083": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-084": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-085": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-086": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-087": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-088": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-089": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-090": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-091": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-092": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-093": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-094": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-095": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-096": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-097": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-098": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    },"order-099": {
        "destination" : "YVR"
    }
}
```

Comment: Class `Schedule` uses simple strings for `Source` and `Destination`.  I would think a robust solution would have a `City` class where you can have the City Name, Airport code, and *TIme Zone*.  Consider that `Montreal` and `Vancouver` are in different time zones, which affects duration of flights.

Comment: @RickDavin Thanks for the suggestion. That would be a great addition/extension to the code, but do you see any improvement in the existing code?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem I see is that you use dependency injection (DI) and factory method in a project that doesn't require it.

```
var defaultFlightScheduleInstance = flightScheduleFactory.GetFlightTypeScheduelInstance(FlightTypeSchedule.DefaultFlight);
var loadedOrderFlightScheduleInstance = flightScheduleFactory.GetFlightTypeScheduelInstance(FlightTypeSchedule.LoadedFlight);
```

can be replaced with

```
var defaultSchedule = new DefaultFlightSchedule(scheduledRepository);
var loadedSchedule = new LoadedFlightSchedule(orderRepository, scheduledRepository);
```

and the factory is not necessary anymore. Automated DI doesn't serve any pupose either considering there are about 5 classes in total.

For the interviewer it may look like you're overcomplicating things unintentionally or trying to show off your knowledge of those techniques. None of this is any good.

Naming is on point and the algorithm seems good unless performance is an issue (in which case you shouldn't be using LINQ).

---

The following are just nitpicks:

`List<Order> loadedOrders = new List<Order>();` is a perfect use case for `var` which you use pretty much everywhere else.

`GetFlightTypeScheduelInstance` - use a typo detector.

```
//use auto properties
public int FlightNumber { get; set; }
public string Source { get; set; }
```

```
//use string interpolation
return $"{FlightNumber}. Source: {Source},  Destination: {Destination}, Day: {Day}";
```

These comments don't contain any information that we can't infer by simply reading the code. Comments should explain not *what* the code is doing, but *why* it has to be done.

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
      services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
      services.AddScoped<IScheduleRepository, ScheduleRepository>();
      services.AddScoped<IFileReader, JsonFileReader>();
      services.AddScoped<FlightScheduleFactory>();
})
.Build();
```

is not properly formatted. Try this:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
                                      services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
                                      services.AddScoped<IScheduleRepository, ScheduleRepository>();
                                      services.AddScoped<IFileReader, JsonFileReader>();
                                      services.AddScoped<FlightScheduleFactory>();
                                    })
                 .Build();
```

Now as all methods in the chain are indented equally, it becomes much more clear what's going on. In the first version it's hard to tell what unindented `.Build();` is used on (it's actually `Host` surrounded by text some lines before).

Answer (score 2):

> how are we going to find the orders not loaded on any flights if order collection is part of Flight class?

The outgoing orders will be instantiated and then flights will have references to them.

The InventoryManager

```
public class InventoryManager {
   protected Orders OrdersOutbound = new Orders();
   protected FlightSchedule Schedule = new FlightSchedule();

  public void LoadSchedule() {
      forEach(var flight in Schedule)
        flight.Load( OrdersOutbound.ToSomewhere(flight.Destination));
        
      Schedule.Sort();
   }
}
```

A flight gives each loaded order a reference to itself

```
public class Flight : IComparable {
  public void Load(Orders moreOrders) {
    if (moreOrders == null) return;
    
    forEach(var order in moreOrders)
      order.Load(this);
      
    Cargo.Add(moreOrders);
  }
}
```

And an Order keeps a reference to that flight

```
public class Order : IEquatable, IComparable {
    public void Load(Flight theAirplane) { this.Airplane = theAirplane; }
}
```

And the InventoryManager can track things:

```
InventoryManager Mac = new InventoryManager(dataSource);
// schedule is loaded in the constructor. 
// just simple expediency for this illustration

Console.WriteLine(Mac.LoadedOrders());
Console.WriteLine(Mac.NotLoadedOrders());
Console.WriteLine(Mac.LoadedOrders("YCC"));
Console.WriteLine(Mac.NotLoadedOrders("YVR"));
```

---

---

Snippets above are from the following code.

For illustration only. Does not fully meet all problem
statement requirements.

OO highlights:

- constructors guarantee valid objects and consistant initial state.
- I have all classes override `ToString`. A class should format its own data for itself. Besides, it is very helpful during development.
- Implementing `IComparable` means default/reuseable collection sorting
- Implementing `IEquatable` defines identity equality. Tracking Orders requires defining uniqueness within the scheduling system
- Separation of model from UI. No class calls `Console` methods.
- Model is decoupled from the data source
- Constructor use means that class properties are not arbitrarily null nor have invalid values; far less "guard code" in the using classes.
- A class does not set other class' properties directly.
- As a whole the classes define a "Scheduling API".

  - Collections encapsulate `List<T>`. You cannot call its methods.

.

```
public class Flight : IComparable {
 protected int Number         { get;  set; }
 protected int Day            { get;  set; }
 protected int Origin         { get;  set; }
 protected string Destination { get;  set; }
 protected Orders Cargo       { get;  set; }
  
  public Flight (string origin, string destination, flightNumber = null, flightDay = null, Orders cargo = null) {

    if ( origin.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() || destination.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() )
      Throw new ArgumentMissingException ("Flight constructor origin or destination is missing");
      
    Origin = origin; Destination = destination;
    flightNumber ?? 0 : flightNumber;  flightDay ?? 0 : flightDay;
    Cargo = cargo ?? new Orders() : cargo;
  }
  
  public bool isScheduled() { return (Day != 0 || Number != 0); }
  public bool isLoaded() { return Cargo.length > 0; }
  
  public void Load(Orders moreOrders) {
    if (moreOrders == null) return;
    
    forEach(var order in moreOrders)
      order.Load(this);
      
    Cargo.Add(moreOrders);
  }
  
  public void UnLoad() {
    forEach(var order in Cargo)
      order.Unload();
      
    Cargo.Clear();
  }
      
  // order by Day then Number
  public bool CompareTo (Flight thatFlight) {
    if (thatFlight == null) return 1;
    if (this.Day > thatFlight.Day) return 1;
    if (this.Day < thatFlighjt.Day return -1;
    if (this.Day == thatFlight.Day) return CompareNumber(thatFlight);
  }
  
  protected bool CompareNumber(Flight thatFlight) {
    return this.Number.CompareTo(thatFlight.Number);
  }
  
  public override string ToString() {
    return String.Format( "Day: {0}, Flight: {1}, departure: {2}, arrival: {3} \\n \\n {4} \\n",
                          Day, Number, Origin, Destination, Cargo.ToString() );
  }
  
} // Flight


public class Order : IEquatable, IComparable {
    protected int Priority { get;  set; }
    protected string Number { get;   set; }
    public string Destination { get;  set; }
    protected Flight Airplane { get;  set; }
    
    public Order (string number, string destination, string priority} {
      if ( number.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()      ||
           destination.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ||
           priority.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()    || )      
        Throw new ArgumentMissingException ("Order constructor parameter missing");
           
      Number = number; Destination = destination; Priority = priority;
    }
    
    public bool isLoaded() { return this.Airplane != null; }
    
    public void Load(Flight theAirplane) { this.Airplane = theAirplane; }
    
    public void UnLoad() { this.Airplane = null; }
    
    public bool Equals (Order that) {
      return String.Equals(this.Number, that.Number);
    }
    
    public int CompareTo (Order thatOrder) {
      if (thatOrder == null) return 1;
      return string.Compare(this.Number, thatOrder.Number);
    }
    
    public override string ToString() {
      return String.Format( "Number: {0} | Priority: {1} | Destination: {2}", 
                               Number, Priority, Destination );
    }

} // Order


public class Orders {
  protected List<Order> Orders {get; set;}
  
  public Orders(Orders someOrders = null) {
    Orders = someOrders ?? new Orders() : someOrders;
  }
  
  public Orders ToSomewhere(string destination) {
    Orders destined = new Orders();
    destined.Add(Orders.Find(x => x.Destination == destination));
    return destined;
  }
  
  public void Add(Order another) {
    if (another == null) return;
    if (Orders.Contains(another)) return;
    
    this.Orders.Add(another);
  }
  
  public void Add(Orders someOrders) {
    if (someOrders == null) return;
    
    this.Orders.Add(someOrders);
  }
  
  public override string ToString() {
     StringBuilder me = new StringBuilder();
     this.Orders.Sort();  
     
     forEach(var order in this.Orders) {
       me.AppendLine(order.ToString());
     }
     
     return me.ToString();
  }
  
} // Orders


public class FlightSchedule {
  protected List<Flight> Schedule {get; set;} 
  
  public FlightSchedule () {
    Schedule = new List<Flight>();
  }
  
  public void Add( Flight another){
    if (another == null) return;
    
    Schedule.Add(another);
  }
  
  public override string ToString() {
    StringBuilder me = new StringBuilder();
    Schedule.Sort();
    
    forEach(var flight in Schedule) 
      me.AppendLine(flight.ToString();
      
    return me.ToString();
  }
  
} // FlightSchedule


public class InventoryManager {
   protected Orders OrdersOutbound = new Orders();
   protected FlightSchedule Schedule = new FlightSchedule();
   protected ???? rawData; 
   
   public InventoryManager(??? dataSource) {
     BuildSchedule(dataSource);  // magic happens. 
     CreateOrders(dataSource);  // magic happens
     LoadSchedule();
   }
   
  public void LoadSchedule() {
      forEach(var flight in Schedule)
        flight.Load( OrdersOutbound.ToSomewhere(flight.Destination));
        
      Schedule.Sort();
   }

   public Orders LoadedOrders() {
     Orders loadedOrders = new Orders();       
     loadedOrders.Add(OrdersOutbound.Find( x => x.isLoaded()));
     return loadedOrders;
   }
   
   public Orders LoadedOrders(string destination) {
     Orders loadedOrders = new Orders();       
     loadedOrders.Add(OrdersOutbound.Find( x => x.isLoaded() && x.Destination == destination);
     return loadedOrders;
   }
   
   public Orders NotLoadedOrders() {
     Orders notScheduled = new Orders();
     notScheduled.Add(OrdersOutbound.Find( x => ! x.isLoaded());
     return notScheduled;
   }  
   
   public Orders NotLoadedOrders(string destination) {
     Orders notDestined = new Orders();
     notDestined.Add(OrdersOutbound.Find( x => (! x.isLoaded()) && x.Destination == destination);
     return notDestined;
   }       

} // InventoryManager
```

---

---

---

**Conflating Schedule and Flight**

These should be separate classes. The requirements show these are distinct things.

> ... Only 2 days of flights are scheduled

and

> Day 1:  Flight 1: Montreal airport (YUL) to Toronto (YYZ) Flight 2: Montreal (YUL) to Calgary (YYC) Flight 3: Montreal (YUL) to Vancouver (YVR)

A schedule is composed of flights, they are not the same thing.

---

**Conflating cargo loaded state and schedule class**

This mis-conceptualization underlies the Schedule classes design, discussed later.

> Each plane has a capacity of 20 boxes

The problem states flatly that "... 3 planes are scheduled to fly daily at noon" without qualification as to cargo on board.

```
class Order {
  public bool IsNotLoaded() { return Schedule == null; }
 }
```

cargo is put on a flight. The flight is scheduled to fly - i.e. is assigned a takeoff time.

---

**`Order.isNotLoaded` Double Negativity**

Change method name, and logic, to `IsLoaded` and the returned boolean is more intuitive.

```
public bool IsNotLoaded() { return Schedule == null; }
```

If scheduled, that logic is:

- "it is false that the cargo is not loaded"

---

**`Orders` collection**

There are requirements for displaying order status. An `Orders` collection will be the way to view the schedule from an orders perspective. Easy to get status on all orders regardless of where they are.

---

**Inventory Manager**

Separate class because it is a distinct task in the problem statement.  Sounds like a potentially complex thing so better its own class. Also because putting this function in any other class is a Single Responsibility Principle violation.

---

**The Schedule Concept**

A schedule is a collection of flights. I infer from the problem statement that when a flight is given a takeoff date/time it is "on the schedule." Scheduling  a flight is independent of putting cargo on board.

`Schedule` and `Flight` classes must contain their functionality, not distributed amongst different Types. Given that, there is no justification for the different `xxxFlightSchedule` classes nor DI.

It is simply wrong that as schedules dynamically change state, they should change type.

Look at .NET collection classes and see how `find()` methods take expression parameters for filtering.

`ToString` does not need different implementations. `Flight.ToString` will always say how much cargo is on board, even it is "none."

This output

```
order: order-001, flightNumber: 1, departure: <departure_city>, arrival: <arrival_city>, day: x ...
```

can be in the `Order` class.

Remove: `public enum FlightTypeSchedule`. It is an invalid concept

---

**Schedule Design Reflecting Requirements**

There are 3 classes claiming to be "schedules." However there are not 3 different "schedule" concepts imbedded in the problem statement (requirements). Conversely there is not a single "schedule" concept in code. For a singular "schedule" concept there is no unifying design. For multiple concepts there are only code fragments.

Either way the classes are incoherent because none of the following is true: common inheritance, common `interface`, polymorphic "core schedule" functionality, regardless.

---

**SOLUTION**

One `Schedule` class. It is fundamentally a collection of `Flight` objects. `Find()` methods to filter as needed to meet problem requirements.  `ToString()` does not call `Console.Write`.

`Flight` class. Contains a `Orders` collection object.

`Orders` class. An instance for 'to be assigned` as well as for each flight.

Every class implements `ToString()` for itself.

.NET collection classes implement `IEquatable` and `IComparable` as needed. Supports uniqueness (flight number, order number), prevents duplication, w/in a collection. Supports sorting, say by order number, arrival time, destination, etc.

Comment: Apologies for asking this but could you please share some code because I lost you between the comments on my code and the solution you shared. Also, I did not get your below comment in Solution: "Orders class. An instance for 'to be assigned` as well as for each flight."

Comment: Replace `DefaultFlightSchedule` and `LoadedFlightSchedule` with the concept that An `Order` is a box of stuff we want to Ship from A to B. `Orders` is many `Order` objects grouped into a collection. `Orders` is a class.   Given all existing individual `Order` objects we gather them into groups, for example orders on a given flight. Another may be all `Order` boxes going to destination "B".  Another may be all orders scheduled to ship today. Another may be all orders in existence.   DO NOT CREATE CLASSES - `LoadedFlightSchedule` for example - for what are simple filtered  sets of `Orders`.

Comment: how are we going to find the orders not loaded on any flights if order collection is part of Flight class?